# Visual Studio 2012: How can I fix a missing (corrupted?) C++ project configuration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am having issues with a C++ project in Visual Studio. If I open my configuration manager and check the project context configuration dropdown, one of my configurations is missing from the list.

The configuration is still listed on the main Visual Studio toolbar, and in the active solution configuration dropdown of the configuration manager.

Now this is where it gets weird:
If I create a new solution configuration, the previously missing configuration appears in the project configuration dropdown (but the newly created configuration does not). You would think that this would fix the problem, except that the next time I load the solution, the new solution appears and the one that was missing is gone again.

I'm fairly certain that some file is corrupted somewhere, but don't know where to look or how to fix it. I have all of my configuration settings copied to a spreadsheet, so in the worst case scenario I can recreate my project, but I would like to know what is causing the problem in the first place.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can't you just pull a recent good version of the project from your version control system or from a backup ?

Comment: I checked an older version of the project. I was sure it was working at that time, since I compiled a working library file from it and I don't remember having any issues getting there. But when I go back to it now it's having the same problem.

Comment: Going through my .sln and .vcxproj files, I noticed that there were some discrepancies in the configuration lists. Once I made sure that the lists in both files matched, I reloaded my solution and the problem was gone.